# Save the orientation of a RGL plot3d() plot

Tags: r, rgl

I have a 3D plot using RGL. I would like to make identical plots using color to highlight the distribution of some variable. To do this I would like to have identical plots, how do I find and set the orientation of a plot?

Once I make a preliminary plot, I move it around to find a nice display angle and I would like to save that angle and incorporate it into future plotting scripts. Anyone have a suggestion on how to do this?

```
library(rgl)
plot3d(iris) 
#play with the plot to find a good angle
#save the angle for future plots
```

Comment: try `pp <- par3d(no.readonly=TRUE); ...; par3d(pp)`

Comment: also - is there a good way to hardcode it - i,e, save `pp` as a variable that I can incorporate into a future script without recalculating?

Comment: Also check out `?rgl.viewpoint`

Comment: Thanks James. I could imagine taking the output of the par3D() call and hardcoding the view into my script using rgl.viewpoint - great tip.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ben's comment basically answers your question; this just applies `expand.dots` to what he wrote ;)

```
## In an inital session:

library(rgl)
plot3d(iris) 

## Now move the image around to an orientation you like

## Save RGL parameters to a list object
pp <- par3d(no.readonly=TRUE)

## Save the list to a text file
dput(pp, file="irisView.R", control = "all")

.......

## Then, in a later session, to recreate the plot just as you had it:

library(rgl)
pp <- dget("irisView.R")
plot3d(iris)
par3d(pp)
```

Comment: It's safer to use `control="all"` in the `dput()` line, as that saves all of the deparsing information and ensures that the result of dget works.

Comment: Without `control="all"` I got an error *incorrect number of dimensions*, because dget() incorrectly flattened the userMatrix to a list.

Comment: @AssadEbrahim -- Thanks for noting that! I just edited the answer incorporate your suggested improvement.