# shiny app rglwidget get userMatrix to generate another plot with same rotation

Tags: r, shiny, rgl

I have a shiny app and integrate an rgl 3d-plot into it. I am using `renderRglwidget` from the `rglwidget` package to insert the rgl graphics using webgl into my shiny app.

In the app the user can rotate the graphic. Now I want to save the rotation state, hence the userMatrix or modelMatrix to later generate a similar plot with the same rotation as the user left the previous graph.

[Here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/vignettes/WebGL.html#viewport) I read something about java variables storing the userMatrix and other parameters. Can I access them from within my shiny app (in R code)?

In rgl itself I can use `rotationMatrix <- rgl.projection()$model` or `rotationMatrix <- par3d()$modelMatrix`  to store the rotation of the model. But since in my case the graphic is not rotated in rgl itself these functions don't help me.

What I tried is this:

```
library(shiny)
library(rgl)
library(rglwidget)

ui <- fluidPage(
  rglwidgetOutput("3D-plot"),
  actionButton("showMatrix", "show rotation Matrix")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  open3d(useNULL = T)
  x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
  y <- rnorm(1000)
  z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x, y)
  plot3d(x, y, z, col = rainbow(1000))
  scene1 <- scene3d()
  rgl.close()

  output$"3D-plot" <- renderRglwidget({
    rglwidget(scene1)
  })
  observe({
    input$showMatrix
    par3d()$modelMatrix
  })
}


shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

But `par3d()$modelMatrix` does not seem to return anything.

Comment: I don't see how your Shiny app is doing anything to display the matrix, but I don't know Shiny well enough to know that it is wrong.  Just in case it is fine:  the open3d() function returns a value of the rgl device number that was opened, and par3d() has an optional argument "dev" that can query a specific device.  Perhaps if you use those you'll get what you want.

Comment: Got any feedback for me?

Comment: Are you there? Did you try my answer?

Comment: It has been awhile, but this was a lot of work. Any chance you could accept it?

Comment: I am sorry for letting you wait so long. Yes, on my second try your code worked excellent! I think I just did something wrong on my first attempt. I am still not there, where I wanted to go with it, but that is my fault. You answered everything that I asked for here. I will give you a bounty for your effort and for letting you wait so long!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason `rgl:par3d()` does not return anything is because the `rgl` packages is not actually managing the scene for shiny. The javascript based `rglwidget` library that leverages `WebGL` is managing it, and you are copying over the scene to another very compatible GL library (maybe they even use the same compiled library, but I doubt it) and displaying that in shiny. So `rgl.dev()` will not help you.

AFAIK, it is not easy to get at these values as they are hidden away in `rglwidget` javascript, but I wanted to get at them, so I built a shiny custom input control that can do it. It was a fair amount of work, and there might be an easier way, but I didn't see it and at least I know how to build custom input controls for shiny now. If someone knows an easier way, please enlighten me.

Here is the javascript, it goes into a `www` subfolder that you save in the same directory as your shiny code.

## rglwidgetaux.js

```
// rglwidgetaux control for querying shiny rglwiget

var rglwidgetauxBinding = new Shiny.InputBinding();
$.extend(rglwidgetauxBinding, {
  find: function(scope) {
    return $(scope).find(".rglWidgetAux");
  },
  getValue: function(el) {
    return el.value;
  },
  setValue: function(el, value) {
  //  $(el).text(value);
     el.value = value;
  },
  getState: function(el) {
    return { value: this.getValue(el) };
  },
   receiveMessage: function(el, data) {
    var $el = $(el);

    switch (data.cmd) {
       case "test":alert("Recieved Message");
                    break;
       case "getpar3d":
                    var rglel = $("#"+data.rglwidgetId);
                    if (rglel.length===0){
                       alert("bad rglwidgetId:"+ data.rglwidgetId);
                       return null;
                    }
                    var rglinst = rglel[0].rglinstance;
                    var sid = rglinst.scene.rootSubscene;
                    var par3d = rglinst.getObj(sid).par3d;
                    this.setValue(el,JSON.stringify(par3d));
                    $el.trigger("change"); // tell myself that I have changed
                    break;
    }
  },  
  subscribe: function(el, callback) {
    $(el).on("change.rglwidgetauxBinding", function(e) {
      callback();
    });
  },
  unsubscribe: function(el) {
    $(el).off(".rglwidgetauxBinding");
  }
});
Shiny.inputBindings.register(rglwidgetauxBinding);
```

Here is the R/shiny code. It uses the usual test scene and has a button to query the scenes `userMatrix` and displays it in a table. I used the `userMatrix` and not the `modelMatrix` because the former is easy to change with the mouse, so you can see that you are getting the freshest values.

Note that the name "app.R" is not really optional. Either you have to use that, or split the file into "ui.R" and "server.R", otherwise it will not import the javascript file above.

## app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(rgl)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(jsonlite)

rglwgtctrl <- function(inputId, value="", nrows, ncols) {
  # This code includes the javascript that we need and defines the html
  tagList(
    singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src = "rglwidgetaux.js"))),
    tags$div(id = inputId,class = "rglWidgetAux",as.character(value))
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    rglwgtctrl('ctrlplot3d'),
    actionButton("regen", "Regen Scene"),
    actionButton("queryumat", "Query User Matrix"),
    rglwidgetOutput("plot3d"),
    tableOutput("usermatrix")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) 
{
  observe({
    # tell our rglWidgetAux to query the plot3d for its par3d
    input$queryumat
    session$sendInputMessage("ctrlplot3d",list("cmd"="getpar3d","rglwidgetId"="plot3d"))
  })

  output$usermatrix <- renderTable({
    # grab the user matrix from the par3d stored in our rglWidgetAux
    # note we are using two different "validate"s here, which is quite the pain if you 
    # don't notice that it is declared in two different libraries
    shiny::validate(need(!is.null(input$ctrlplot3d),"User Matrix not yet queried"))
    umat <- matrix(0,4,4)
    jsonpar3d <- input$ctrlplot3d
    if (jsonlite::validate(jsonpar3d)){
      par3dout <- fromJSON(jsonpar3d)
      umat <- matrix(unlist(par3dout$userMatrix),4,4) # make list into matrix
    }
    return(umat)
  })

  scenegen <- reactive({
     # make a random scene
     input$regen
     n <- 1000
     x <- sort(rnorm(n))
     y <- rnorm(n)
     z <- rnorm(n) + atan2(x, y)
     plot3d(x, y, z, col = rainbow(n))
     scene1 <- scene3d()
     rgl.close() # make the app window go away
     return(scene1)
  })
  output$plot3d <- renderRglwidget({ rglwidget(scenegen()) })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

And finally here is what it looks like:

[image]

Note that I set it up so you can add commands to it, you could (probably) change  parameters and anything else with a control based on this one.

Also note that the `par3d` structure here (converted to json and then to R from the `rglwidget` javascript) and the one in `rgl` are not quite identical, so for example I had to flatten the `userMatrix` as WebGL seems to prefer it as a names list as opposed to the other matrices which came over as expected.

Comment: No comment on this?

Comment: Thank you very much for all the effort you put into this! I think this should find it's way into the rglwidget package! I could not test it though. Where exactly do I have to put the javascript file? I put it in .www relative from the shiny file but the browser cannot find it.

Comment: Stange. www not .www, right? Worked for me using chrome or the RStudio viewer. same as any Shiny custom input control.

Comment: yes, I put it in www. I will give it another try this afternoon.

Comment: How did it go? I tried it again, works fine for me. Thinking about adding a `setpar3d` to this example, should be easy.

Comment: Works for me also.

Comment: @MikeWise If you had gone so far to dig the `par3d` of `rglwidget`, maybe now it would be simple to *set* the `par3d` according to the last scene's one? This has been asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435356/shiny-rgl-plot3d-keep-plot-view-orientation-on-replot and has not received a satisfactory solution yet. Would be awesome to have one :)

Comment: Ah, thanks for alerting me to this. Been busy with other stuff, will have a look.