# How to keep camera orientation fixed in an interactive 3D plot in R/Shiny

Tags: r, 3d, shiny, rgl

I have a 3D rgl plot that users can modify based on some inputs (you can see it in action at https://magalab.shinyapps.io/rgl_test/). But every time the user modifies the input settings, renderer returns to the initial orientation to redraw the model. I want to keep the orientation consistent between updates. I know how to do that in rgl, and there is already another similar question 
([Shiny RGL Plot3D: Keep Plot View Orientation On Replot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435356/shiny-rgl-plot3d-keep-plot-view-orientation-on-replot)), which did not receive any answer.

There is potentially a relevant topic at [shiny app rglwidget get userMatrix to generate another plot with same rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837472/shiny-app-rglwidget-get-usermatrix-to-generate-another-plot-with-same-rotation), but I don't want to see the `userMatrix`, simply pass it to the `open3d()`.

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with `Javascript` and `Shiny` to achieve this. Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: I think the approach in Mike Wise's answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837472/shiny-app-rglwidget-get-usermatrix-to-generate-another-plot-with-same-rotation should work.  You don't need to display the matrix, that was just to show that it was successfully retrieved.  But you are going to need to learn more about Shiny to modify his answer to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the very newest `rgl` (version 0.99.18, currently only on R-forge), there's a function called `shinyGetPar3d` that is designed to do what you want.  See `example(shinyGetPar3d)` for a demonstration of how to use it.